# Appending one file to another

Tags: shell, cp

Simple question. I'm trying to append one file to another. I've tried this:

`cp temp1 >> temp2 temp3`

But, it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: That's *three* files. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Append `temp1` to `temp2`, `temp3` is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append a file to another:

```
cat input_file >> output_file
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you much. I can't believe I forgot how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

To create temp3 file as a concatenation of the files temp1 and temp2 :

```
cat temp1 temp2 > temp3
```